# Cleaning a Talis together with silver Atora

Tags: tallit-gadol, washing-clothes, metals

Can I wash my heavy wool talis together with the silver Atora,what happens if I won’t remove the Atora? I will appreciate if anyone can assist me,thank you!

Comment: Are you asking whether this is permissible according to Jewish law, or are you asking if this is advisable from a laundering perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you live. In Brooklyn, Lakewood and other areas where there is a large Jewish population, the dry cleaners will take off the Atara, clean the Talis, reconnect the Atara and your Talis and Atara will look sparkling clean.

I do not think it is a good idea to put an Atara in the washing machine.

You can also contact [Mefoar Judaica](https://mefoarjudaica-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/mefoarjudaica.com/amp/silver-atarah-cleaning/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15939883406071&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fmefoarjudaica.com%2Fsilver-atarah-cleaning%2) and they offer cleaning and shipping for an Atara.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are willing to go the dry cleaning route where they remove
   the atarah and reattach it, that's the best way to go but it will cost.
2. If you are on a low budget, check the two answers [how to wash it by
   hand](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/how-should-a-tallit-gadol-be-washed) but keep in mind that you will need to be prepared to
   properly iron it as otherwise it might look like "you slept  in it"
   sort of look. This is not as easy as it sounds as wool is sometimes
   hard to iron because it can be easy to make creases in the wrong
   places. Also, it's very big and hard to manage on a typical ironing
   board.
3. If you want to use a washing machine, put it in a pillowcase or some
   protective washable material, use a wool cycle which is usually very
   gentile and uses a lot of water and little agitation (vs. a regular
   cycle) and take it out of the machine after a couple of revolutions
   in the spin/rinse cycle so most of the water is extracted but the
   atarah is not abused. Be prepared to be near the washing machine
   to be able to to this at the right time.