Tips on whitening a Talit
Talits get yellow over time. Source - go to any shul and look at the old Talits, or if you've had yours for 5-10 years, look at yours and compare to brand new. Also note the stains.
Dry cleaners never get my Talit any whiter, nor do they do well getting out the stains either.
Given that it is not something you can just put in the washing machine with bleach (unless you know what you are doing I guess? Especially if there is any colour other than white on the Talit), and there are complications such as concern about the tzitzit, and maybe even potential halachic considerations, I thought it a good question to ask here:
Any solid tips or tricks on whitening a Talit, and removing its stains properly so it looks "new" again (as much as possible)?

Dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/how-should-a-tallit-gadol-be-washed#

This question is similar to: How should a tallit gadol be washed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
